# Setting spring.profiles.active from an environment variable in Spring Boot with Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My company has a standard way to specifying the environment a web service should run in, specifically 'development' and 'production' by using an environment variable APP_ENV. Each of these environments have a separate config file: application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml.

In spring boot, we can use SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE or equivalents to do this, but what I really want to do is grab the VALUE from APP_ENV, and use that as the profile.

I've got some code

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
springApp.setAdditionalProfiles(System.getenv("APP_ENV"););
springApp.run(args);
```

Any tips on how to do this a bit cleaner? I'm getting
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` errors on various gradle tasks that make this solution kind of flimsy.

Answer (score -1):

you can use System.getProperty which will always return a String like below,

```
springApp.setAdditionalProfiles(System.getProperty("APP_ENV", "dev"));
```

In the above snippet, we use System.getProperty(“APP_ENV”) to extract the value of the property APP_ENV. We also are making use of the default value so if the property is not available in the system, getProperty returns dev.

Comment: this isn't that helpful, its almost exactly a copy of the code I linked